# magento: Add product from front end

Tags: magento, e-commerce, frontend, product

Can anyone help me by some idea that how can I Add products  from the front end with most of the attributes of the products in Magento?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
//$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
//echo time();
// Build the product
$product->setAttributeSetId(9);// #4 is for default
$product->setTypeId('simple');

$product->setName('Some cool product name');
$product->setDescription('Full description here');
$product->setShortDescription('Short description here');
$product->setSku(time());
$product->setWeight(4.0000);
$product->setStatus(1);
$product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);//4
//print_r(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);

$product->setPrice(39.99);// # Set some price
$product->setTaxClassId(0);// # default tax class

$product->setStockData(array(
'is_in_stock' => 1,
'qty' => 99999
));

$product->setCategoryIds(array(27));// # some cat id's,

$product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1));// # Website id, 1 is default

//Default Magento attribute

$product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));


//print_r($product);
try {
    $product->save();
    echo "Product Created";
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    //Handle the error
    echo "Product Creation Failed";
}
```

I have used this and it worked. I also found this from a site but forgotten the link :(

Comment: can you please tell me how can i set image also , the above code is works like a magic thanks a lot it really helps me

Comment: @RohitGoel You may try $product->setImage($base64ImageContent);
 Please look http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/43450/

Comment: I want to give link in the left menu of customer so where do you do this exactly ? can you please help ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the frontend with 'custom product attributes' to collect the information (and image) needed to add a product.

Then you can have your own backend code to take an 'order' and build products from those custom product attributes.

Comment: Yes I have made that in your way probably

Comment: Can you guys add more detail for this

Comment: Its shared in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Products can be uploaded and managed from magento frontend using magento [Rest/Soap api](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html).
.This extension also does the same.Have a look at:
[Frontend Products Upload](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/supplier-frontend-products-upload.html)

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses the backend for adding products to your store.Adding it from frontend changes the whole scope from security and integrity point of view. Why the need for adding from frontend when you can do the same from backend with full priviliges?

Comment: I will only add product for a particular category. So security should not affect.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible out-of-the-box. But you can write your own custom module for this, it will not be very big and complicated.

Comment: But i have made it for a category