# Magento: adding product from frontend form

Tags: magento, addition, frontend

I have magento demo shop and for example i want registered user to be available to post a product from frontend? Can anyone hook me up with some code showing how to make it? Is it even possible in magento?

Comment: Please check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675867/magento-add-product-from-front-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible. It actually shouldn't be all *that* difficult. You're going to create a module, programmatically create an order, and link this page from somewhere. You should be able to hack one together with the following resources:

- [Programmatically Creating Orders - Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/)
- [Creating a Custom Module part 1-8](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento/)

Answer (score 0):

yes dear it is possible, you have to create a module for that and i think you give to link/tab in customer account page in front side.in account page you provide form of add new product.you have also provide all option like in magento back end. but some customization are required